# Ruby on Rails site accessible during business hours only

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to make my Rails site only accessible during business hours.

I could change the message on the homepage and remove the login during non-business hours.

Or I could redirect to another page after logging in... that tells the user the site is not accessible during business hours.

Or I could redirect all menu links to a page saying the site is not accessible during non business hours.

But I have no idea how to even start on this... or where to put this logic.

Any help, please?

Comment: Make a decision to go with one of them. Then try to implement it. When you have an question concerning the code you've written, post it here. SO isn't made to determine your software requirements.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a specific answerable programming problem.

Comment: thank you Reinhard... I was hoping someone would give me direction on which to go with... Rails or JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

You can have the logic inside application controller which can render a different page or layout when time is other than office hour.

Comment: Good idea @rakeshp ...  IAlso, logged-in visitors on the site should be logged out during non-business hours. I really appreciate your advice... do you think that's possible using the application controller?  I'm kinda new to this... and any advice u can give is greatly appreciated! –

Comment: Yes, you can set before_filter in application controller, so that all the request coming to the application can be redirected to different action  based on the time.

Answer (score 0):

I know this does not directly answer your question, but I think this is not exactly a task for a Rails application but rather for the web server that sits in front of it (assuming you have one). This is doable in nginx and Apache, I didn't check other web servers.

- for nginx: https://miteshshah.github.io/linux/nginx/nginx-time-based-rewriting-rules/
- for Apache: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/advanced.html#time-dependent

Comment: Thank you, katafrakt... It's a Rails app hosted on Heroku... 

I'd like to restrict visitors from logging in except during business hours.

Also, logged-in visitors on the site should be logged out during non-business hours.

I really appreciate your advice... do you think those time-based rules can be used with Heroku?

I'm kinda new to this... and any advice u can give is greatly appreciated!